# How to get uiimagepicker Spinner button action in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm using below code.

```
 self.picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 self.picker.delegate=self;
 self.picker.allowsEditing=NO; 
 self.picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 self.picker.cameraOverlayView=[self addCameraRollButton];
 [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

How to take picture from camera without going to Usephoto page. I want to stay on camera view. I'm not able to get camera spinner action.I used custom overlay but in that Square focus not coming.Please help me.I want all default camera features.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use custom overlay you will not be able to see default camera features.If you want all default features you should use

```
self.picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

This opens default camera and you can see all features.
If you want to go with custom overlay then you need to built all features.

Comment: Yes, But it is moving usephoto i don't want to move this page. square auto focus not coming in custom overlay.